# What are some syntax options for iterating over arrays?

Tags: syntax, arrays, iterators

What are some different syntax choices for loops that iterate over arrays? Of course, there is the common `for` loop:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    myArr[i]
}
```

But this isn't the only option. What are some others?

Answer (score 11):

Functional languages may have a higher-order function (not a list method!) which takes a function/lambda/operator and one (or more!) arrays, and iterates over them. E.g. APL and BQN have *Each* (`¨`) which, together with *Take* (`↑`) allows us to take various prefixes from a corresponding number of strings:

```
      3 1 4↑¨'Hello' 'There' 'World'
┌───┬─┬────┐
│Hel│T│Worl│
└───┴─┴────┘
```

We can of course also use it with a single list, here with Reverse (`⌽`):

```
      ⌽¨'Hello' 'There' 'World'
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│olleH│erehT│dlroW│
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Note that `¨` is not something built into the lists, as we can assign the result of `¨` combining with an operation:

```
      ReverseEach←⌽¨
      ReverseEach 'Hello' 'There' 'World'
┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│olleH│erehT│dlroW│
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Answer (score 9):

## For each function

Some languages have a ‘forEach‘ function on their lists that takes a list and a lambda, and applies that lambda to each item. For example, Kotlin:

```
list.forEach { item -> 
    println(item) 
}
```

Comment: This also exists in JavaScript

Answer (score 9):

## for-in

This is the approach taken by Swift and Python:

```swift
for el in arr {
  print(el)
}
```

JS does something similar, but for historical reasons it uses `of` instead:

```js
for (const el of arr)
  console.log(el);
```

Comment: It's confusing in JS because `in` actually loops over the keys

Comment: PHP uses `foreach ($arr as $el)`, which is backwards

Comment: PHP's syntax should probably be its own answer, then.

Comment: JS `for...of` uses `[Symbol.iterator]` as the iterator too

Comment: And Rust... and Kotlin...

Answer (score 6):

**Functor fmap**

For repetitive (but not only) tasks over a structure like an Array, I like the Functional Programming point of view: map/fmap  syntax

The goal of it is pretty similar to foreach in imperative languages

If you happen to have any structure that is a candidate for being a Functor (there are only a few features to respect for this), and lists / arrays are Functors, in Haskell, you can do this:

```
fmap myFunction myArray
```

Once accustomed to it, for me it is difficult to want to use something else.
myFunction can of course be a short lambda definition

```
fmap (\x -> x+1) myArrayOfXs
```

In case you have a computation that is more than reading or doing simple stuffs, you can also use the more elaborated mapM, but then we enter the realm of Monads. I just mention it here.

And finally, there's Traversable typeclass/interface to iterate over Traversable containers: not only can you iterate and have behaviour during the iterationm, but you can even create a structure issuing from the iteration.

Answer (score 4):

### Java for each

```java
for (int item : myArr) {
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

This style is easier, as we don't need to keep track of an iterator variable (like `i`), and instead we can work directly with `item` instead. It does come with a tradeoff when `item` is a *copy* of an item in `myArr`, as we can't easily modify the original array

```java
for (int item : myArr) {
    // this changes item, but not the original item in myArr
    item = 0;
}
```

Comment: "*It does come with a tradeoff when item is a copy of an item in myArr, as we can't easily modify the original array*" that's true in Java but does not have to be true in general: `item` might be a reference to the array slot, thus `item = 0` could directly manipulate the array. I don't know of any language that does this with a for-each but it still could be done.

Comment: @VLAZ-onstrike- I think rust can do that with `iter_mut`

Comment: C++ has that, `for (int& item : arr)`. In fact, I've seen at least as much "borrowing" `for (const auto& item : arr)` as I have copying `for (auto item : arr)`.

Comment: @VLAZ-onstrike- PHP does that in `foreach ($arr as &$item) {}`: the `&` indicates using a reference. You do need to `unset($item)` at the end of the loop or you get weirdness.

Answer (score 4):

## Backwards foreach

PHP uses this:

```php
foreach ($arr as $el) {
  ...
}
```

I think there might also be a language that uses something like `foreach (arr => el)`, but I don't remember what.

Comment: You can also use `($arr as $key=>$value)` for associative arrays

Answer (score 4):

## for range

https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/16

```go
for index, value := range data {
    fmt.Printf("2**%d = %d\n", index, value)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Iterating over multiple arrays together, and in fixed-size chunks

Below are quoted from the Tcl man page. Note that in Tcl, arrays are read into a list in a single level by the format `{key value key value ...}` that odd elements are keys, and even elements are values, which is probably why it would be helpful to iterate in chunks. The part about iterating over multiple arrays would be much more useful in other languages. It also has a variant version `lmap` which works like `foreach` but also collects the result. `{}` denotes an empty string.

The following loop uses `i` and `j` as loop variables to iterate over pairs        of elements of a single list.

```
set x {}
foreach {i j} {a b c d e f} {
    lappend x $j $i
}
# The value of x is "b a d c f e"
# There are 3 iterations of the loop.
```

The next loop uses `i` and `j` to iterate over two lists in parallel.

```
set x {}
foreach i {a b c} j {d e f g} {
    lappend x $i $j
}
# The value of x is "a d b e c f {} g"
# There are 4 iterations of the loop.
```

The two forms are combined in the following example.

```
set x {}
foreach i {a b c} {j k} {d e f g} {
    lappend x $i $j $k
}
# The value of x is "a d e b f g c {} {}"
# There are 3 iterations of the loop.
```

Answer (score 2):

## C# foreach

```cs
foreach (int number in Numbers) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same as [Java](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/a/704/7)?

Comment: @Adám - no, as it uses an additional keyword `in` rather than punctuation `:`.  There are pros and cons for the two choices, so it's worth listing both.

Answer (score 2):

## Generator Functions

```lua
for key, value in pairs(table) do
    print(value)
end
```

[Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/7.3.html) doesn't support table iteration as a keyword directly, instead relying on generators to do the heavy lifting.

This is notably different from languages like Python and C# in that the `for` keyword does not support directly iterating over any object, only generator functions.